# What does NSXMLParserUndeclaredEntityError mean?

Tags: cocoa

When using NSXMLParser, what does `NSXMLParserUndeclaredEntityError` mean? Apples documentation is completely unhelpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the `NSXMLParserUndeclaredEntityError` when you use a special character that isn't expected by the NSXMLParser for example `&foo;`

The only valid special characters that the `NSXMLParser` will recognize are:

```
&lt;
&gt;
&apos;
&quot;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the first answer on [Resolving html entities with NSXMLParser on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370842/resolving-html-entities-with-nsxmlparse-on-iphone) where it lists the standard supported entities. Are you able to post your XML that you're parsing?